# how can I use Vue.js to render two dimensional table?

Tags: vue.js

I want to use vue to render a long table.But here is my problem:

```
     <table>
            <tr><th v-for="item in columns">{{item}}</th></tr>
            <tr v-for = "item in data">{{item.buyerNick}}</tr>
     </table>
```

when I use tag "th" with "v-for",it works well.But when I use tag "tr", it says

```
ReferenceError: item is not defined(…)
```

then I change "tr" to "div", it works. How can I render rows in table using Vue.js.

Comment: Is this what you want jsFiddle( https://jsfiddle.net/r_vamsi_krishna/dsezdx8f/ )

Comment: It would be helpful to see what's in `data`

Comment: try to replace {{item.buyerNick}} to <td>{{item.buyerNick}}</td>. For a complete answer we need to know more about the data.

Comment: @VAMSIKRISHNA I don't know how to render mulitple rows. This example only have one rows. I mean if you have 100 rows and two-dimensional data . How can you render it in table.

Comment: `tr v-for`, then nested `td v-for`. Show your `data` which you loop through. In your question you're trying to insert text into rows, instead of cells.

Comment: @edisonxue or this jsFiddle(https://jsfiddle.net/r_vamsi_krishna/dsezdx8f/1/)

Comment: @wostex oh,I see.